# Using ntlk sum up attributes when a certain frase occurs

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nltk

I am new to python so pls help ) 
I have a dataframe that looks like this :
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fVpw.png)

I managed to count all occurrences of each bigram that you can see in the code, but I also need to sum up the other values where this certain bigram is a part of.

Tried iterating through the dataframe with a custom dictionary and ran into lot of problems.

```
import nltk

nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
nltk.download('punkt')
counts = collections.Counter()
for sent in df["Search term"]:
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(sent)
    counts.update(nltk.bigrams(words))

counts.most_common(10)
```

my attempt i made looked like this, but I cant make it iterate trough bigrams:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
word_dictionary = dict()

for row in df.itertuples():
  words = nltk.word_tokenize(str(row[0]))
  print(nltk.bigrams(words))
  for bigram in nltk.bigrams(words):
    print(bigram)
    if bigram in word_dictionary:

        word_dictionary[bigram][0], word_dictionary[bigram][1] = (word_dictionary[bigram][0] + row[14]) , (word_dictionary[bigram][1] + row[15])  
    else:
         word_dictionary[bigram]= (row[14]) , (row[15])

print(word_dictionary)
```

the end result should be a sorted dictionary like (by the first value, say items) where I dont care much about the formatting:

go to (23, 30)
to go (10, 15)

etc...

Comment: Please describe your desired data structure better, and please include what "problems" you are experiencing, as well as what your code is doing right now. It helps us to identify where the discrepancies are.

Comment: I tried my best and added a picture =)